# Very strange stringstream and std::getline behaviour

Tags: c++, string, stream, std, getline

I'm fightning with a map loading bug in my engine, and finally I found it. However, it seems it's something wrong with stringstream and getline... Minimal code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string text = "1!2!6|6|5|";
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << text; // insert to buffer

    std::string temp;
    buffer >> temp; // extract
    buffer << temp; // then insert again (i need it in my code to count characters)
    // and I can't count it before, as in my code the buffer is filled from file

    std::string loaded;
    std::getline(buffer, loaded, '!'); //should instert "1" to loaded
    std::cout << loaded; //and it displays nothing, debugger shows loaded is empty
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug? I'm using g++ 4.7 c++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For extracting the string from stringstream in this case, you probably want:

```
temp = buffer.str();
```

instead of:

```
buffer >> temp;
```

See: [extracting formatted (interpreted) data](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) vs. [stringstream.str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/)

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer when it will be possible.